# SwitchMap and PublishReplay in combination

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am working on an Angular project and I don't fully understand why this code snippet is not working as expected:

```
const httpObs = Rx.Observable.of("")
  .do(() => console.log("trigger http call")) //only triggered once
  .publishReplay(1).refCount();

let observable = Rx.Observable.timer(0,1000)
  .do((e) => console.log("new event: " + e))
  .switchMap(() => this.httpObs);

const c1 = observable.subscribe(() => console.log("subscriber 1"));
const c2 = observable.subscribe(() => console.log("subscriber 2"));
```

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/wigiwocamu/edit?html,js,console)

I don't understand why "trigger http call" is not triggered with each event that is emitted by Rx.Observable.timer. My expectations are that every emitted event triggers the http call as soon and as long as one subscriber is subscribed to the observable. However, every subscriber receives the same emissions, which implies that there is just one http call per event.

I know that I could fix it by using publishReplay + refcount on the observable (see below) but this would just work in this simple example.

What I really try to achieve is that two components use the same response of an http call and each components emits an onInit event, which is then switchMapped to the http-response. I don't want every new subscriber to trigger the call. However, I want the call to be triggered when another event is emitted. The onInit observable is merged with a click-observable that emits new events whenever the user clicks on "update" button, before the switchMap operator is used to transform the. The problem is now, that the update button does not trigger the http call anymore.

This example shows how it should behave:

```
const httpObs = Rx.Observable.of("")
  .do(() => console.log("trigger http call"));

let observable = Rx.Observable.timer(0,1000)
  .do((e) => console.log("new event: " + e))
  .switchMap(() => this.httpObs)
  .publishReplay(1);

observable.subscribe(() => console.log("subscriber 1"));
observable.subscribe(() => console.log("subscriber 2"))

observable.connect();
```

[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/jonaxusoco/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that all Subject instances have their internal state and when they receive `complete` or `error` notifications they mark themselves as "stopped" and will never ever emit anything (this is the requirement for the so called Observable contract). You can have a look at this article https://medium.com/@martin.sikora/rxjs-subjects-and-their-internal-state-7cfdee905156 I wrote some time ago. It coveres very similar topic.

In your code you're using the same `httpObs` multiple times but the source Observable is `of()` that emit a single value and then sends the `complete` notification.

See that it's really called: http://jsbin.com/fuvuxax/2/edit?js,console

```
const httpObs = Rx.Observable.of("")
  .do(() => console.log("trigger call"), undefined, () => console.log('complete'))
  .publishReplay(1).refCount();
```

This means that **the Subject inside `publishReplay` received the `complete` notification** and is not going to subscribe to its source Observable again. However, since `publishReplay` uses internally `ReplaySubject` it will still flush its buffer and then send the `complete` notification. But this isn't very useful for you because I think you want to perform the HTTP call again and not just replay the obsolete one.

What you can do is turning the `httpObs` into a method that creates the chain every time `switchMap` receives a value:

```
const httpObs = () => Rx.Observable.of("")
  .do(() => console.log("trigger call"), undefined, () => console.log('complete'));

let observable = Rx.Observable.timer(0,1000)
  .do((e) => console.log("new event: " + e))
  .take(3)
  .switchMap(() => this.httpObs())
  .publishReplay(1).refCount();

observable.subscribe(() => console.log("subscriber 1"));
observable.subscribe(() => console.log("subscriber 2"));
```

You can see that this prints `"trigger call"` only three times which is I think what you want if I understand your description correctly:

```
"trigger call"
"subscriber 1"
"subscriber 2"
"complete"
"trigger call"
"subscriber 1"
"subscriber 2"
"complete"
"trigger call"
"subscriber 1"
"subscriber 2"
"complete"
```

Comment: I'll need some time to understand what it means, but thanks a lot for your help and the very detailed answer!

Comment: btw there is a little mistake in this example: // http://jsbin.com/hotidih/5/edit?js,console - it should be replay.subscribe(... in the last line

Comment: I have just noticed that your example does not solve the issue, because it is basically similar to my second snippet. What I try to achieve is a shared httpObs observable, which takes care that new subscriptions (e.g. from another components) don't trigger the call because of new subscriptions but only when new events are emitted.

Comment: @Daniel I don't know what you want to do, you'll need to show me what output you expect.

Comment: the same output you created, but in a different way. Image httpObs is in a service and "observable" is a component and there are multiple components observing the httpObs. I tried to sum it up in this example: http://jsbin.com/bikubujufu/edit?js,console